# Create contract for creating accounts in ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I want create accounts in ethererum server using

curl command and geth.

just like this

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["restart"],"id":74}' http://0.0.0.xxx:8545
```

can i create contract for creating the accounts throught api?

Comment: You want a smart contract to create an account? Why? Smart contracts only live on the blockchain, they have no way to create a key pair and add it to your geth node.